# PKIX path building failed in Java application

Tags: java, exception, ssl, certificate

I have been struggling for almost one week to get my applications up running after moving my applications from Windows 2000 to Windows 2008 R2 Server.

The procedure:

1. Installed Java JDK 1.7.0_25
2. Set system environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\`
3. Imported the certificate into cacerts with `keytool`
4. Ensured that the certificate exists in `keytool` with `-list`.

I have tried to repeat *step 3* with `InstallCert` to ensure that i havent messed anything up.

The above methods did not solve my problem, so i tried to do it programmatically:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
"C:/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

Still without any luck. I am stuck and not quite sure which direction to go from here.

Stack trace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at util.SMS.send(SMS.java:93)
    at domain.ActivationSMSSenderMain.sendActivationMessagesToCustomers(ActivationSMSSenderMain.java:80)
    at domain.ActivationSMSSenderMain.<init>(ActivationSMSSenderMain.java:44)
    at domain.ActivationSMSSenderMain.main(ActivationSMSSenderMain.java:341)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 20 more
```

**UPDATE:**

Both 
`System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));` 
and 
`System.out.println(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));`

returns `null`.

Comment: have you added your intermediate certs?

Comment: Im not quite sure which you mean, but i haven't touched the default certificates in cacerts.

Comment: intermediate cert refers to your cert issuer. if your cert issuer is not trusted, your cert is also untrusted. for example, to authenticate google.com, you will also need to add Google Internet Authority and GeoTrust to truststore.

Comment: So if i open the `Certification path` in Chrome, i see a tree structure `Geotrust Global CA -> RapidSSL CA -> *.thedomain.com`. I need to add the two first aswell?

Comment: yes, they are required.

Comment: The GlobalCA was already added, but RapidSSL was missing. Unfortunately it did not solve my problem..

Comment: Can you show the output of your program when you run it with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`?

Comment: beny23, the output is rather long, where should i include this?

Comment: I have uploaded the dump on pastebin http://pastebin.com/W3Akw4M9

Comment: @Diego Magdaleno I tried all the steps to import thirdparty certificate in cacerts as you mentioned however I still get same Exception

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I ran into similar issues whose cause and solution turned out both to be rather simple:

**Main Cause**: Did not import the proper cert using keytool

*NOTE: Only import root CA (or your own self-signed) certificates*

*NOTE: don't import an intermediate, non certificate chain root cert*

**Solution Example for imap.gmail.com**

1. Determine the root CA cert:

   ```
   openssl s_client -showcerts -connect imap.gmail.com:993
   ```

   in this case we find the root CA is *Equifax Secure Certificate Authority*
2. Download [root CA cert](https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem).
3. Verify downloaded cert has proper SHA-1 and/or MD5 fingerprints by comparing with info [*found here*](https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/)
4. Import cert for `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`:

   ```
   keytool -import -alias gmail_imap -file Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem
   ```
5. Run your java code

Comment: In case you have many JRE installed, you can specify the keystore you want to import the certificate adding `-keystore path/to/jre/lib/security/cacerts` to the command in the step 4.

Answer (score 10):

You've imported the certificate into the truststore of the JRE provided in the JDK, but you are running the java.exe of the JRE installed directly.

**EDIT**

For clarity, and to resolve the morass of misunderstanding in the commentary below, you need to import the certificate into the `cacerts` file *of the JRE you are intending to use,* and that will rarely if ever be the one shipping inside the JDK, because clients won't normally have a JDK. Anything in the commentary below that suggests otherwise should be ignored as not expressing my intention here.

A far better solution would be to create your *own* truststore, starting with a copy of the `cacerts` file, and specifically tell Java to use that one via the system property `javax.net.ssl.trustStore.`

You should make building this part of your build process, so as to keep up to date with changes I the `cacerts` file caused by JDK upgrades.

Comment: Yes, because you've imported the certificate into one truststore and you're using another one. Do read the answer.

Comment: EJP, i think i understand now. But i have tried to initialize the certificates into `cacerts` aswell, without any difference.

Comment: @JavaCake every JRE has a `cacerts` keystore. What EJP is saying to you, is to make sure that when you run the program the JRE of the JDK (with the `cacerts` where the certificate is imported) is used and not some other JRE installed in your machine. Use `System.getProperty("java.runtime.version")` to check if this is actually the case

Comment: According to the full stacktrace it looks right. I have reported this error to our servicedesk, because theres not much i can do now. All the certificate which should be necessary are initialized.

Comment: @c.s. Absolutely not. I have not said anything of the sort. He has imported the certificate into the wrong truststore for the JRE he is running. The correct response would be to import it into the correct truststore, not to change the JRE being used. Not every installation would even have a JDK.

Comment: @EJP I have not suggested to change the JRE. I have just elaborated on your answer

Comment: @c.s. You have suggested to use a specific JRE, which is the exact opposite of what I wrote above. I repeat. You are not 'elaborating on' but misrepresenting my answer. I further quote: 'what EJP is saying to you is ...' By this formula you have put words into my mouth that I did not utter, and you have attributed views to me when they are your own views not mine. Don't do that. If you want to to post your own answer go ahead, but you needn't presume to add your own glosses to what I have clearly written here. I am not in any need of being misinterpreted and misrepresented here by you.

Comment: @EJP I can still not understand where the "suggest to use a specific JRE" comes from, but anyway. I thought I was elaborating on your answer but if that was not the case then your point is fair enough. If I misunderstood what you said or if I offended you in any way please accept my sincere apologies. That was not my intention

Comment: @c.s. You wrote, and I quote: 'make sure that when you run the program the JRE of the JDK (with the cacerts where the certificate is imported) is used and not some other JRE installed in your machine'. I really should not have to quote your own words at you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Eclipse just cross check in Eclipse **Windows--> preferences---->java---> installed JREs** is pointing the current JRE and the JRE where you have configured your certificate. If not remove the JRE and add the jre where your certificate is installed

Answer (score 0):

Per your pastebin, you need to add the `proxy.tkk.com` certificate to the truststore.

Comment: Do you know how i can retrieve the certificate for proxy.tkk.com? This is a local proxy. I assumed that `InstallCert` handled all certificate dependencies.

Comment: If all of your connections are going through an SSL-inspecting proxy, you'll need the generic certificate which is signing all of the pseudo-certs for the sites visited.  This is likely installed in the browser trust stores, or you should be able to get it from the proxy admin.

If you're not going through the proxy for these connections, you simply need to get the 'correct' certificate for the sites you're trying to trust, which appear to be issued by RapidSSL and not proxy.tkk.com.  The server admins can provide these, or you can get them from outside the proxy environment.

Comment: In my other web based applications that do not require SSL i need to use the proxyHost parameter to get access, but that is not enough in this case i assume.

Comment: Ahhhh, and you are not doing so here?  That is, are you going around the proxy to make this connection?

Comment: Without the proxyHost parameter i get a `HTTP 407`.

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows** you can try these steps:

1. Download a root CA certificate from the website.
2. Find a file jssecacerts in the directory `/lib/security` with JRE  (you can use a comand `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home");` to find the folder with the current JRE). Make a backup of the file.
3. Download a program [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/).
4. Open the jssecacerts file in portecle.
5. Enter the password: changeit.
6. Import the downloaded certificate with porticle (Tools > Import Trusted Certificate).
7. Click Save.
8. Replace the original file jssecacerts.

Answer (score -2):

In my case the issue was resolved by installing **Oracle's official JDK 10** as opposed to using the default OpenJDK that came with my Ubuntu. This is the guide I followed: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/install-oracle-java-10-in-ubuntu-or.html

Comment: It's not the real solution. OpenJDK just works. Abusing the word "official" doesn't help. OpenJDK has been the reference implementation of Java for years (since Java 7 as far as I remember). Your problem was probably elsewhere.