# Alfresco SSL handshake exception

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat6, alfresco

I have downloaded and installed Alfresco 4.0c, the installation seemed to be successful. I can also login succesfully on Alfresco Share: `http://localhost:8080/share/`. I can also login succesfully on `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/`.

After starting Alfresco and logging into Alfresco Share. I get a huge error log in `Alfresco/tomcat/logs/stdout_########.log`

The error is the following

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
```

You can find the full log [here](http://pastebin.com/fAJgkhCY).
The security contract seems to be expired. Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: can you please also put log here.

Comment: Her you go http://pastebin.com/fAJgkhCY

Comment: Below links will solve your issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378869/pkix-path-building-failed-in-java-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr search engine which was introduced in alfresco had issue with it's certificate validity date, 
So all alfresco 4.0.x version has this issue which cause breaking of solr search.
To fix that you need to follow steps mentioned in this forum post.

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/announcements/important-ssl-certs-solr-alfresco-4-expire-week-08152012-1307