# Spring boot redirected to 403 Forbidden page after authenticated with keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, keycloak

**Original question:**

I am deploying a keycloak and a spring boot application that using the keycloak, both in docker container. I am using nginx as reverse proxy.

Keycloak exposed as 9001 (http) and 9005 (https). My spring boot applicaiton exposed as 9002.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sso.examle.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate  ssl/sso.examle.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  ssl/sso.examle.com.key;

    location /auth/ {
        proxy_http_version                  1.1;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:9001;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.examle.com alias examle.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate  ssl/www.examle.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  ssl/www.examle.com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version                  1.1;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:9002;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    }
}
```

I was successfully open my keycloak and configure without problem. My problem is when my spring boot application trying to authenticate through keycloak, it redirected to `https://www.examle.com:0/sso/login?state.........`

Is it related to the nginx configuration?. If you need more information let me know.

**UPDATE:**

Finally, the redirection issue was solved with the following header in nginx configuration:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
```

My problem now is I get 403 Forbidden status in the /sso/login page, so it is related to the spring boot configuration.
[image]

This is the spring boot SecurityConfig configuration:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
       return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home*").hasRole("user")
                .antMatchers("/home/*").hasRole("user")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

And this is the properties:

```
server.port=8080
server.ssl.enabled=false
keycloak.realm=${KEYCLOAK_REALM}
keycloak.auth-server-url=${KEYCLOAK_URL}
keycloak.resource=${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID}
keycloak.credentials.secret=${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET}
keycloak.ssl-required=external
```

This is the spring boot log related to the error:

```
2018-05-13 17:00:46.414  WARN 30 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.k.a.s.a.KeycloakLogoutHandler          : Cannot log out a non-Keycloak authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6fa8940c: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 172.19.0.1; SessionId: CC029C9E7F1B796E54CB6B6FAB4675C6; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2018-05-13 17:00:50.190 ERROR 30 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : failed to turn code into token
web          |
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:114) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:557) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:109) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
 at org.keycloak.adapters.ServerRequest.invokeAccessCodeToToken(ServerRequest.java:111) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
 at org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.resolveCode(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:336) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
 at org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:281) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
 at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:139) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
 at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:147) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67) [spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) [spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.3.Final.jar:3.4.3.Final]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 ... 86 common frames omitted
```

**Update:**

someone maybe wonder how to setting the truststore keycloak in spring boot. Firstly, [convert my ssl keys to jks format](https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/steps-to-create-a-jks-keystore-using-key-and-crt-files). Then copy the jks to `/src/main/resources`. Then add following spring boot properties:

```
keycloak.truststore=classpath:mykey.jks
keycloak.truststore-password=mypassword
```

Comment: Can you show us further configuration (keycloak.json, SecurityContext.java...)?

Comment: @XtremeBiker, sure

Comment: The error you've got now is not spring boot related, but it is with java. JVM has a set of certs which trusts in by default. Which cert do you use for your site? You might need to import it to cacerts. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24705398/1199132

Comment: I am using comodo as CA, I wonder why it trusted by web browsers, not in JDK (i'm using JDK 8 inside docker)

Comment: Regarding to comodo root certs, they seem to have done some inclusion/exclusions in 51 and 101: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml

Comment: thanks @XtremeBiker, you solved my problems