# Error while consuming secure SOAP base web service in JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, soap

**I am new in JAVA**, Consuming web service(.wsdl) in **Web Service Client** project. I import the client certificate in java **cacerts** store in **jrd**. My code is as follows:

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","[PATH]/cacerts.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");

        ServicesProxy service = new ServicesProxy();
        ServiceRequest request = new ServiceRequest(1498);
        ServiceResponse response = service.getDetails(request);
```

I'm failed to handshake, I am getting the following exception:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
    PKIX path building failed:
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
    unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have no clue why there is an exception. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is that using Apache CXF as the web services client?  This uses its own SSL settings in the `cxf.xml` file - more details [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-ConfiguringSSLSupport)

Comment: Are you sure the name of your truststore is `cacerts.jks` and not just `cacerts`?

Comment: I tried with cacerts too.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to add the key chain in the certificate (PEM format).

CA Root -> Intermediate Cert -> Cert.

Or the certificate cannot be found in the keystore, do you use the correct alias etc.

And I do not recognize the SOAP JAX-WS implementation you use.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution to your problem, but maybe it helps to find it:
You can start your client with the VM parameter `-Djavax.net.debug=all` which will give you a lot of information about the SSL connection.

Check here for details about the output:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Answer (score 2):

Use -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore  property directly instead.

One more thing the server you use in that also u need to place the jks for handshake.

For example server is JBoss then bin

Answer (score 2):

I guess your cacert is not correct or the path is unaccessible. I followed the instructions given [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html)

> Use SSL Poke to verify connectivity

1. Download [SSLPoke.class](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/files/779355358/779355357/1/1441897666313/SSLPoke.class)
2. Execute the class as follows, changing the URL and port:

   > $JAVA_HOME/bin/java SSLPoke yoururl 443
3. A successful connection would look like this:

   > $JAVA_HOME/bin/java SSLPoke yoururl 443
   >
   > Successfully connected
4. Try to use a different truststore to connect

   > $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=[PATH]/cacerts.jks SSLPoke yoururl 443

If it fails the truststore does not contain the proper certificates.

**How to solve it**

The solution is extracted from [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-import-a-public-ssl-certificate-into-a-jvm-867025849.html)

1. Fetch the certificate again from the server:

   > openssl s_client -connect yoururl:443

You need openssl. Save the output to a file called public.crt. This is how your file should look like:

```
     -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
     < Bunch of lines of your certificate >
     -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

2. Import the certificate:

   > $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias  -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file public.crt

Enter the password if prompted (the default is changeit)

**Recommendation**

In the same post it is not recommended to use a configured trustStore different than the JVM cacert because then java could not access other root certificates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite common error while dealing with soap services over SSL, I've had it a few times.

Your certificate may not be correctly installed in your truststore.

You can use openssl to check and install the correct certificate in the truststore, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378869/pkix-path-building-failed-in-java-application)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Looks like certificates are not imported correctly or path used in code not pointing to correct keystore.

I hope following steps in below article will help you.

http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html