# Java API connectiong failed: PKIX path

Tags: java, ssl, unirest

I have been seeking for some solutions about **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target** exception, but the solutions that are provided in the posts I read did not solve the issue, that is why I am asking here.

Basically, in my code, I am using Unirest for connection, as the code below:

```
public void httpConnectionHourlyPred() {
   try {
      Map<String, String> asHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
      asHeaders.put("cache-control", "no-cache");
      asHeaders.put("api_key", getsKey());
      HttpResponse response = Unirest.get(sURLHourlyPred).headers(asHeaders).asString();
      System.out.println(response);
}
```

The API to which I am connecting the AEMET Open Data service (https://opendata.aemet.es/centrodedescargas/inicio), while the API endpoint is https://opendata.aemet.es/opendata/api/prediccion/especifica/municipio/horaria/01001. For security reasons, I do not include the API-KEY, but, if I try the API in the browser, I success as the snapshot below.

[image]

The same script for python also works and I got the result. However, due to the use of a hardware only compatible with Java, I have to program in Java. Thus, when I run the script, I obtain the exception below. I am using the OpenJDK virtual machine (in particular, openjdk-8u312-b07). How could I fix it?

Many thanks in advance

```
com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:143)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:56)
    at es.cartif.aemet.AEMETConnector.httpConnectionHourlyPred(AEMETConnector.java:55)
    at es.cartif.main.AEMETMain.main(AEMETMain.java:10)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1497)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:441)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:412)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:290)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:138)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 33 more
Error making the data request javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: By the way, I have tried solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378869/pkix-path-building-failed-in-java-application, but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't configured the ssl configuration of Unirest. The specific exceptions could mean that the server is not trusted by the client. What you could do is extract the certificate from: https://opendata.aemet.es/ which is:

[image: server certificate chain]

I would advice to put the certificate into either a p12 or jks truststore file and create a sslcontext out of it.

Here is a code snippet for creating a sslcontext from a truststore:

```java
InputStream trustStoreStream = ...; // your InputStream from the trust store file

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
trustStore.load(trustStoreStream, "password".toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

And configure your primary instance of Unirest like the snippet below:

```
Unirest.primaryInstance()
    .config()
    .sslContext(sslContext)
```

Comment: Many thanks! I noticed that the Unirest version was not the proper one. I was trying to use the keystore with the certificate, but with the Kong Unirest library, it is working. Thanks!!!